# Wildcards in tag filters sometimes show tags twice

Tags: bug, status-completed

When using wildcards in tag filters, the searched tag is shown twice for some patterns.

For example

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*facebook*
```

results in showing the Facebook tag twice:

> [image: Facebook tag shown twice]

---

Another example showing the searched tag twice:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*magento*
```

> [image: Magento tag shown twice]

---

The issue seems to somehow depend on the tag being searched.

Other patterns, like:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*html*
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*http*
```

work as expected. They do *not* show the searched tag twice.

Comment: Hmm, the ones with the tag replicated also have synonyms for that particular tag. I wonder if that's related? Good catch.

Comment: I could very well imagine that as a plausible reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a minor glitch caused by synonyms, which will be fixed in the next build; basically, after doing the expansion it finds some are synonyms, and does the replacements *over the top* - this means that some got duplicated. This will be fixed in the next build.

Example:

- "abc-def" is a synonym for the master-tag "abc"
- you search for "*abc*"
- it expands to "abc-def abc"
- it then applies synonyms, giving "abc abc"

The order "expand wildcards, then apply synonyms" is intentional, and addresses some edge-cases, i.e. if "ghi" is also a synonym of the master-tag "abc", then searching for "*gh*" will show you the "abc" data.

BTW, the explanation for this is much longer than the fix, which was just "add `.Distinct()`".

For info, the offending synonyms are [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/facebook/synonyms).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is a glitch in the search system (but it makes sense!!!)

Basically (what I think) it is doing is searching for all tags that *end with* `facebook*`, which it only found one: [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook), then it finds all that *start with*  `*facebook` which **includes** [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) (the same goes for your other searches)

The API ***should*** know what the intersections are between those two searches, but it does not seem to be working.

Comment: Hm, no idea whether it's a glitch, but if the search really works the way you think it does, then `*html*` and `*http*` would also produce the tag twice. But they don't...