# Wildcards in tag filters may lead to swallowing entries in "featured" lists

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

This seems to be based on the count of tags being resolved.

For example when viewing the "featured" question for the tag filter `*facebook*`, this is resolved to

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook+or+facebook-graph-api+or+facebook+or+facebook-like+or+facebook-c%23-sdk+or+facebook-javascript-sdk+or+facebook-fql+or+facebook-php-sdk+or+facebook-opengraph+or+facebook-apps+or+facebook-social-plugins+or+facebook-page+or+facebook-comments+or+facebook-iframe+or+facebook-authentication+or+facebook-oauth+or+facebook-canvas+or+facebook-fanpage+or+facebook-wall+or+facebook-login?sort=featured
```

and should list **three**, but shows only **two** "featured" entries:

[image]

Comment: Maybe related to this [bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135475/wildcards-in-tag-filters-sometimes-show-tags-twice)?

Comment: Do you have ignored tags? Maybe 1 question was filtered. When I open this link I only see 1 quesiton.

Comment: @juergend: yes, I have some ignored tags. But even if they are used when generating the result, the shown result count should always match the shown result entry count, shouldn't it?

Comment: @juergend: Seems you're correct. I checked the generated source code of the page now, too. The source code _does_ contain three matches (id="question-summary-<n>", where n in (11962287, 11765053, 12000341), but only two are visible, and the invisible one has a class of "question-summary tagged-ignored-hidden".

Comment: @juergend: Please post your comment as answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the Profile option "Hide ignored tags" then question with the tags you defined as "ignored tags" get **dynamically** hidden.

That does include the search-results page and other question listing pages. If you want all questions to be shown the only option you have right now is to deactivate the "Hide ignored tags" checkbox temporarily in your profile.

Actually there is a feature-request for that [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36735/temporarily-disabling-ignore-tags)

Comment: +1, I was just irritated by seeing "wrong" counts.

Answer (score 2):

[Juergen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/144197/131112)'s answer is correct, some tags were hidden due to your preferences. To clarify the  behavior and make the system more user-friendly we've added the following banner at the bottom of the list:

[image: ignored posts banner]